# SQL syntax error; "check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order INT NOT NULL'

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, syntax-error, create-table

I'm using MariaDB and MySQL and I'm trying to create a table using the command prompt but I'm getting a syntax error and I am unsure what is wrong. Below is the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order     INT NOT NULL,
        FName   VARCHAR(255),
        LName   VARCHAR(255),
        PhoneNum        VARCH...' at line 3
```

Here is what I have:

```
CREATE DATABASE projecttestDB;
USE projecttestDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Staff;

CREATE TABLE Staff (
    Year    INT NOT NULL,
    Order   INT NOT NULL,
    FName   VARCHAR(255),
    LName   VARCHAR(255),
    PhoneNum    VARCHAR(255),
    Salary  INT, 
    CHECK(Salary>=0),
    PRIMARY KEY (Year, Order)
);
```

Comment: Don't use `Order` as a column name, it is a keyword.

Answer (score 4):

`order` is a reserved word in SQL. If you absolutely have to use it, you can escape the column name using backticks:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Staff (
    Year    INT NOT NULL,
    `Order` INT NOT NULL, -- Here!
    FName   VARCHAR(255),
    LName   VARCHAR(255),
    PhoneNum    VARCHAR(255),
    Salary  INT, 
    CHECK(Salary>=0),
    PRIMARY KEY (Year, `Order`) -- And here
);
```

But it's probably a better idea to rename it to something that isn't a reserved word, such as `order_num`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Staff (
    Year    INT NOT NULL,
    Order_Num INT NOT NULL,
    FName   VARCHAR(255),
    LName   VARCHAR(255),
    PhoneNum    VARCHAR(255),
    Salary  INT, 
    CHECK(Salary>=0),
    PRIMARY KEY (Year, Order_Num)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Order* is a system key word. If you change it to something else it will work.